# Center text in List View - Android

Tags: android

This may seem like a duplicate but I can't find an answer anywhere.

It seems everyone has "TextView" available to edit in their activity xml file, whereas I only have the following:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/liv1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lt1"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lt1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lt1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lt1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lt1"
    />
```

Using `android:gravity = center`does nothing when I put it in between the "ListView" brackets.

So what is it I should do?

Comment: Text in list view cannot be centered through tags in ListView itself. If you are using a default adapter then you can't do that. You need to create a class which extends either BaseAdapter or arrayAdapter and provide XML for every Row.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom `ListView` adapter that fits your needs, and also create an inflater's xml layout and align the text there whatever you want.

More info here:

- [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)
- http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Answer (score -2):

You should set gravity in your item, that you using in your adapter. And there modify your textView like this way:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"   <= set this
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/invalid"
android:gravity="center"   <=this your gravity
/>
```